# Arduino Tre, will it ever come out?

Tags: hardware

Does anyone have any information other than "coming soon" about the Tre?

- Could the Tre be stuck in development hell?
- Perhaps the new partnership with Adafruit could expidite things, seeing as Ardiuno (.cc) was touting the Tre to be the first Arduino made in the USA?

I'm just giddily awaiting its arrival, so I'm just wondering!

Comment: Just buy a BeagleBone Black and plug an Uno into it - you'll get pretty much the same thing without having to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest news from Arduino that I can find is in their blog archive that the [second round of beta testing is out](http://blog.arduino.cc/2014/12/12/arduino-tre-developer-edition-2nd-round-of-beta-testing/).

The mentioned this:

> When is the Arduino TRE going to be finally on the market? The board is ready, but we don’t have a final release date yet because we are still figuring out some manufacturing matters. We’ll keep you posted!

I'd imagine that the [Arduino LLC vs Arduino SLR](http://hackaday.com/2015/02/25/arduino-v-arduino/) legal issue is also delaying the production.

Other than that, speculation is all that we know.

P.S: it's still spring until Sunday, June 21! :-)